# wamp https vhost domain redirects to localhost https

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver, httpd.conf

I have setup WAMP on C:\wamp, I followed a tutorial guide to setup HTTPS on my wamp. made ssl with openssl.. I was able to browse **https**://localhost as well as **http**://localhost, the problem is, I have set a couple of virtual host domains in httpd-vhost.conf I can browse them normally as in without **https** BUT when I enter `**https**://domain.local` it redirects to WAMP `**https**://localhost`
I simply can't seem to fix it or get a solution online.. what settings could be causing to redirect to `https://localhost` instead of `https://domain.local`

Comment: Answered on http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,116055

Comment: thanks all cheers.. It works .. I just configured my httpd-vhost.cong file & I can browse my local site in https. Once again thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `var/wamp/www/yourproject/shared/config/config.php`.
Find `('K_REDIRECT_LOGIN_MODE', 4)` and change `4` to `3` *(html redirect)*.